# Distance between ticks in the X axis when plotting time-series in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, axis, x-axis

I am trying to plot a time serie in R using the code below. I need to plot one tick by month but I obtain to many ticks. How can I solve this?

```
library(readxl)
dataset <- read_excel(choose.files())
dataset <- data.frame(dataset)
dataset$Inicio <- as.Date(dataset$Inicio, format=c("%d/%m/%Y"))

plot(Temp.media.de.las.medias ~ Inicio, dataset, col="black", ylim = c(0, 40), type = "l", lwd=2, xaxt='n')
axis(1, dataset$Inicio, format(dataset$Inicio, "%b %m"), cex.axis = .5)

grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,
     lty = 1,      # Grid line type
     col = "gray", # Grid line color
     lwd = 1)
```

[image]

Here my data:

```
dput(head(dataset$Temp.media.de.las.medias, 30))

c(25.36, 25.39, 23.6, 22.53, 23.59, 20.7, 18.99, 18.37, 17.46, 
16.13, 11.82, 14.52, 15.33, 13.39, 13.36, 13.41, 12.96, 10.85, 
8.68, 7.72, 6.04, 8.96, 12.35, 13.52, 11.41, 9.31, 9.72, 12.29, 
14.95, 14.64)

dput(head(dataset$Inicio, 30))

structure(c(17763, 17770, 17777, 17784, 17791, 17798, 17805, 
17812, 17819, 17826, 17833, 17840, 17847, 17854, 17861, 17868, 
17875, 17882, 17889, 17897, 17903, 17910, 17917, 17924, 17931, 
17938, 17945, 17952, 17959, 17966), class = "Date")

class(dataset$Temp.media.de.las.medias)
[1] "numeric"

class(dataset$Inicio)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: It looks like your x-axis is categorical. If not numeric or number-like then reduce the ticks and improving the readability of the axis and its labels is hit-or-miss. Please provide sample data using `dput(head(Temp.media.de.las.medias,30))` please.

Comment: X-axis seems "Date". I added my data according you according to your comment. Thx

Comment: Okay, that's better, but you're asking how to space the data apart on the x-axis, but you are explicitly setting it to be that close together with your call to `axis`, so this is your explicit doing. Why are you overriding `xaxt="n"` and then over-filling the axis?

Comment: I overrode the X-axis because if I don't use `xaxt="n"` I get only one tick per year so my goal is one tick per month. Is there any solution modifying this statement space the data apart on the x-axis?  `plot(Temp.media.de.las.medias ~ Inicio, dataset, col="black", ylim = c(0, 40), type = "l", lwd=2)`

Comment: You cannot have "one tick per month" with that much data without having a lot of ticks. I think I'm not clear on what your intention is, though. Have you considered faceting the plot by year? (not easy with base graphics, but doable, much easier with ggplot2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts:

### base R

```r
plot(Temp.media.de.las.medias ~ Inicio, dataset, col="black", ylim = c(0, 40), type = "l", lwd=2, xaxt='n')
ax <- as.Date(axTicks(1), origin = "1970-01-01")
axis(1, ax, format(ax, "%b %m"), cex.axis = .5)
```

[image: base graphics, default spaced axis labels]

Or if you prefer to have it year-aligned,

```r
plot(Temp.media.de.las.medias ~ Inicio, dataset, col="black", ylim = c(0, 40), type = "l", lwd=2, xaxt='n')
ax <- seq(as.Date("2018-10-01"), as.Date("2019-04-01"), by = "3 months")
axis(1, ax, format(ax, "%b %m"), cex.axis = .5)
```

[image: base graphics, axis labels on quarters]

### ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(Inicio, Temp.media.de.las.medias)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %m")
```

[image: ggplot2 with date labels]

---

Data

```r
dataset <- setDT(structure(list(Temp.media.de.las.medias = c(25.36, 25.39, 23.6, 22.53, 23.59, 20.7, 18.99, 18.37, 17.46, 16.13, 11.82, 14.52, 15.33, 13.39, 13.36, 13.41, 12.96, 10.85, 8.68, 7.72, 6.04, 8.96, 12.35, 13.52, 11.41, 9.31, 9.72, 12.29, 14.95, 14.64), Inicio = structure(c(17763, 17770, 17777, 17784, 17791, 17798, 17805, 17812, 17819, 17826, 17833, 17840, 17847, 17854, 17861, 17868, 17875, 17882, 17889, 17897, 17903, 17910, 17917, 17924, 17931, 17938, 17945, 17952, 17959, 17966), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,  -30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me using `ax <- seq(as.Date(min(dataset$Inicio)), as.Date(max(dataset$Inicio)), by = "2 months")` and then plot it using `axis(1, ax, format(ax, "%b %m"), cex.axis = .8)`